# VB.net Importing empty date into datatable

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code to import data from a CSV file. However some values in the date column are empty and vb.net trows an error. How can I prevent this ?

```
    Dim datatabel As New DataTable()
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PLAASNO", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PLAASNAAM", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("BLOKNO", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("AREA", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DATUM", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("NAME3", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("KULTIVAR", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("WINGKLAS", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ANALISEDATUM", GetType(Date)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SUIKER", GetType(Decimal)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("pH", GetType(Decimal)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SUUR", GetType(Decimal)))


    Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\SKEDULERING\Data\LABANAL2.csv")
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

    parser.ReadLine()

       Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
           Dim data As String() = parser.ReadFields()
          For i As Integer = 0 To data.Length - 1

             If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data(i))) Then
    data(i) = DBNull.Value.ToString
               End If
          Next
           datatabel.Rows.Add(data)

        Loop
```

I suspect my problem is with :

```
             If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(data(i))) Then
                data(i) = DBNull.Value.ToString
             End If
```

The error is : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store  in ANALISEDATUM Column.  Expected type is DateTime

Thank you.

Comment: We need to see a sample of the data to help you convert whatever is in the ANALISEDATUM column of your CSV to a date.

Comment: First make sure that the DB will allow empty dates.  I would add each field item by item to a NewRow, that way you could skip the date when it is missing, leaving it empty.  You could also try to declare `data As Object` since it will be storing string, decimal and date.  Still, just leave that element blank/empty rather than trying to do something with `DbNull.ToString()`

Comment: plaasno,name1,blokno,name2,analise_dt,name3,kult,wingklas,datum,suiker,ph,suur
"08628UIT","MENSIESKRAAL","2-MEN","SPRUITDRIFT","20090115","","SHZ","KULT","  /  /",0.00,0.00,0.00
"11332","MONOTONKA","1-MON","KLEINPLASIE","20090115","","PIN","KULT","  /  /",0.00,0.00,0.00
"11332","MONOTONKA","1-MON","VREDENDAL","20170201","","PIN","KULT","01/02/17",21.10,3.21,8.23
"11332","MONOTONKA","1-MON","VREDENDAL","20170208","","PIN","KULT","08/02/17",24.60,3.44,6.56

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The OLEDB connection will get the excel file and place it into a datatable.

```
                  Public  Shared Function GetCSV as Datatable
                    Dim dt As New DataTable

                                Dim ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "YourFile" & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\"""
                                Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
                                Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " & "YOURFILENAME", conn)
                                da.Fill(dt)


                            Return dt

                    End Function
```